# Check whether value of column exists across Mutiple tables

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Problem:
**I have several tables which have column called "Name". What I'm trying to do is to check whether any of those tables have value "John" in their "Name" columns.**

I'm working on a WPF application, and I'm using Entity Framework (v6.1.3). I assume I cannot use EF for this specific problem, because I'm using Repository pattern, and one repository only works with one table.

If this is not solvable with EF, plain SQL is also okay so that I can finally understand how to do this.

SQL is not my best area of expertise, so thanks up front!

Comment: Iterate through the entities of each DbSet and check whether the Name property of any enities equal to "John"?

Comment: I can't believe that hasn't crossed my mind. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the entities of each `DbSet` and check whether the `Name` property of any entity equals to "John".

Answer (score 1):

You could use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Name FROM tab1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Name FROM tab2
      --...
) AS sub
WHERE sub.Name = 'John'
```

Comment: This works, but I think I'll go with mm8's answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

Check Single Same Record :

```
select * FROM tab1 as t1 with(nolock) where t1.Name in (SELECT t2.Name FROM tab2 as t2 with(nolock) where t2.Name='John')
```

Check Multiple Same Record :

```
 select * FROM tab1 as t1 with(nolock) where t1.Name in (SELECT t2.Name FROM tab2 as t2 with(nolock))
```